# Reload TableView Data from DB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

In my app i git dat from DB by php file in internet and data shown in a Table view but i need to reload my data every minute, i can get the new data every minute but i cant replace it  in the table view.

1) Do you know how to do it?

2) If you know how to get my code more simple, and delete that unNeeded codes? I'll be thanks to you.

My ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tblMain, rows;

NSURL *url;
NSString *jsonreturn;
NSData *jsonData;
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict;
UITableViewCell *cell;
static NSString *CellIdentifier;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self GetData];
}

-(void)GetData{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ar2.co/savola/"];
    jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(jsonreturn);
    jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
    rows = [dict objectForKey:@"savola"];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"company"], [dict objectForKey:@"price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"time"];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a table to reload its information, call `[self.tableView reloadData]` from your view controller class. That will call all of the data source methods again, and it will update the display as well.

Comment: Thanks while(1 == 1){ print(Vere); } Much for the fast answer

Answer (score 1):

You should reload the table after fetching the new data from server. Like in your GetData method :

```
- (void)GetData
{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ar2.co/savola/"];
    jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(jsonreturn);
    jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
    rows = [dict objectForKey:@"savola"];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);

   [yourTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Do this and add an NSTimer to perform this method every minute. Also follow @rishi's advice and complete a check in this method for changes in the data instead of purely downloading the data. Maybe use the network activity indicator too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reloadData` method to reload your table view to display the new data.

But as you mentioned- "but i need to reload my data every minute"

So for this you can check the recieved data with existing data, and if something is changed in new data then only reload the table, else skip that.

If you reload your table every one minute unneccesary without change in data, that will be not correct and also that will slow down your app.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I would recommend you look at using [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It will automatically update you table only when it is required.